# How to programatically open Settings/Preferences window in a macOS SwiftUI App

Tags: macos, swiftui, window, settings, preferences

I have created a simple macOS-only SwiftUI app and added a Settings screen as per [Apple's instructions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/settings):

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            RootView()
        }
        Settings {
            SettingsView()
        }
    }
}
```

It works: the *Preferences* option shows up in the app menu. Now, I would also like to open this settings window programatically, e.g. when a button is clicked. Is there a way to achieve this?

I was hoping there would be a method in `NSApplication`, similar to the *About* window, but there doesn't seem to be one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On macOS 13+, I use this solution:

```
if #available(macOS 13, *) {
    NSApp.sendAction(Selector(("showSettingsWindow:")), to: nil, from: nil)
} else {
    NSApp.sendAction(Selector(("showPreferencesWindow:")), to: nil, from: nil)
}
```

Comment: Will not work on MacOS 14 (Sonoma)

Answer (score 44):

By inspecting the app menu, I found this solution:

```swift
NSApp.sendAction(Selector(("showPreferencesWindow:")), to: nil, from: nil)
```

I assume that it may not pass App Review for using a private API, though, so less shady alternatives are still welcome.

Update: This has actually **passed App Review**, so I had marked it as the answer.

Update 2: For a macOS 13 solution, see [Manny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72803389).

Update 3: For macOS 14 with SwiftUI, you must use the new `SettingsLink` view documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/settingslink). `NSApp.sendAction` no longer works.

Comment: Can confirm in 2022, works like a charm

Comment: I'm on macOS Ventura and this doesn't work anymore

Comment: I got it working thanks to https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711940?answerId=726331022#726331022

Comment: On macOS Sonoma DB1, that would not work anymore, you will get an error "Please use SettingsLink for opening the Settings scene.", so you need to use SettingsLink

Comment: @outcoldman, If you post this as an answer, I‘ll gladly mark it as correct.

Comment: For macoS 14 you may want to use this: https://github.com/orchetect/SettingsAccess

Comment: 2023: DOES NOT WORK for macOs Sonoma ( 14 )  and Ventura (13)

Answer (score 30):

On macOS 13+ versions the action name **has been renamed** to `Settings`.
So to update Joshua's answer, here is the solution to use:

```
NSApp.sendAction(Selector(("showSettingsWindow:")), to: nil, from: nil)
```

I wonder if there is a settings scene id we can use with the new `openWindow` environment method. :)

Comment: Will not work on MacOS <13 & MacOS >13; Will work only on MacOs 13.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution for **macOS <=12 (Monterey and older), 13 (Ventura) & 14 (Sonoma)**:

```
if #available(macOS 14.0, *) {
    SettingsLink {
        Text("Settings")
    }
}
else {
    Button(action: {
        if #available(macOS 13.0, *) {
            NSApp.sendAction(Selector(("showSettingsWindow:")), to: nil, from: nil)
        }
        else {
            NSApp.sendAction(Selector(("showPreferencesWindow:")), to: nil, from: nil)
        }
    }, label: {
        Text("Settings")
    })
}
```

Comment: There's the added inconvenience in Sonoma/SwiftUI of not being able to set any variables (which tab should be shown) before the settings window appears. The only workaround I have for now is setting the value with an onHover. Anyone else have a better solution?

Answer (score 4):

My take on the answers which have already been given is to probe the application delegate for selector response. This has worked well for me so far:

> **2023 Update | macOS 14 Sonoma**
>
> Apple has added a private property to `NSMenuItem` which contains a type-erased function. For the *Settings...* menu item of the application menu, this is what receives the user's click. In the extension below, reflection via `Mirror` is used to extract and call that function.
>
> Because Apple did not include the appropriate identifier values for the *Settings…* `NSMenuItem`, and they have elected to use a generic selector, the only portable discriminator is the item title — localized to the user's preferences.

```swift
import SwiftUI;

fileprivate let kAppMenuInternalIdentifier  = "app"
fileprivate let kSettingsLocalizedStringKey = "Settings\\U2026";

extension NSApplication {
    
    /// Open the application settings/preferences window.
    func openSettings() {
        // macOS 14 Sonoma
        if let internalItemAction = NSApp.mainMenu?.item(
            withInternalIdentifier: kAppMenuInternalIdentifier
        )?.submenu?.item(
            withLocalizedTitle: kSettingsLocalizedStringKey
        )?.internalItemAction {
            internalItemAction();
            return;
        }
        
        guard let delegate = NSApp.delegate else { return }
        
        // macOS 13 Ventura
        var selector = Selector(("showSettingsWindow:"));
        if delegate.responds(to: selector) {
            delegate.perform(selector, with: nil, with: nil);
            return;
        }
        
        // macOS 12 Monterrey
        selector = Selector(("showPreferencesWindow:"));
        if delegate.responds(to: selector) {
            delegate.perform(selector, with: nil, with: nil);
            return;
        }
    }
    
}

// MARK: - NSMenuItem (Private)

extension NSMenuItem {
    
    /// An internal SwiftUI menu item identifier that should be a public property on `NSMenuItem`.
    var internalIdentifier: String? {
        guard let id = Mirror.firstChild(
            withLabel: "id", in: self
        )?.value else {
            return nil;
        }
        
        return "\(id)";
    }
    
    /// A callback which is associated directly with this `NSMenuItem`.
    var internalItemAction: (() -> Void)? {
        guard 
            let platformItemAction = Mirror.firstChild(
                withLabel: "platformItemAction", in: self)?.value,
            let typeErasedCallback = Mirror.firstChild(
                in: platformItemAction)?.value
        else {
            return nil;
        }
            
        return Mirror.firstChild(
            in: typeErasedCallback
        )?.value as? () -> Void;
    }
    
}

// MARK: - NSMenu (Private)

extension NSMenu {
    
    /// Get the first `NSMenuItem` whose internal identifier string matches the given value.
    func item(withInternalIdentifier identifier: String) -> NSMenuItem? {
        self.items.first(where: {
            $0.internalIdentifier?.elementsEqual(identifier) ?? false
        })
    }
    
    /// Get the first `NSMenuItem` whose title is equivalent to the localized string referenced
    /// by the given localized string key in the localization table identified by the given table name
    /// from the bundle located at the given bundle path.
    func item(
        withLocalizedTitle localizedTitleKey: String,
        inTable tableName: String = "MenuCommands",
        fromBundle bundlePath: String = "/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework"
    ) -> NSMenuItem? {
        guard let localizationResource = Bundle(path: bundlePath) else {
            return nil;
        }
        
        return self.item(withTitle: NSLocalizedString(
            localizedTitleKey,
            tableName: tableName,
            bundle: localizationResource,
            comment: ""));
    }
    
}

// MARK: - Mirror (Helper)

fileprivate extension Mirror {
    
    /// The unconditional first child of the reflection subject.
    var firstChild: Child? { self.children.first }
    
    /// The first child of the reflection subject whose label matches the given string.
    func firstChild(withLabel label: String) -> Child? {
        self.children.first(where: {
            $0.label?.elementsEqual(label) ?? false
        })
    }
    
    /// The unconditional first child of the given subject.
    static func firstChild(in subject: Any) -> Child? {
        Mirror(reflecting: subject).firstChild
    }
    
    /// The first child of the given subject whose label matches the given string.
    static func firstChild(
        withLabel label: String, in subject: Any
    ) -> Child? {
        Mirror(reflecting: subject).firstChild(withLabel: label)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: will not work on Sonoma (14)

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_WAR_IN_UA, it looks like there's some really opaque behavior in Sonoma. The `_target` property on the *Settings…* menu item is an internal Swift type, `MenuItemCallback` which does not respond to the selector applied on the item itself, `menuAction:`. IMO, this is an extremely awful decision, because it throws a wrench in the way `NSResponder` is designed to work. I've updated the solution to account for this.

Comment: It opens "About" instead of settings on Sonoma :) Because of "about" and "settings" both are have `Selector(("menuAction:"))`; Have any other ideas?

Comment: And by the way, you don not need to write ";"  at the end of an each line when you're using swift language

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_WAR_IN_UA That's interesting. The selector on my test for *About* was `orderFrontAboutApp` (or something along those lines — I'm not in front of it at the moment). I was trying to avoid using the title as a discriminator in order to avoid localization issues, but you could do that or, alternatively, perhaps discriminate by offset?

I know Swift doesn't require the `;`, but it's a personal choice. In any given week, I might swap between a few different languages, and not all of them are as forgiving as Swift, so I just keep the habit to curtail other issues.

Comment: Looks like the reason is that I'm using custom about window with ```.commands {CommandGroup(replacing: CommandGroupPlacement.appInfo) { Button("menu_line_about".localized(Bundle.main.appName)) { appDelegate.openAboutWnd() } } }```

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_WAR_IN_UA I did look for another internal id value on which to discriminate when I was assembling the solution earlier today and didn't see anything, unfortunately. In a custom scenario like your own, I might opt for the offset-based option since you'll be able to provide the conditions needed to ensure the correct item is used.

Comment: Works for me on Sonoma (14)

Answer (score 0):

The following works by creating your own settings window and hiding it as soon as the application launches. Hopefully Apple improves SettingsLink and/or exposes an API to open settings in the future.

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow

    var body: some View {
        Button("Settings...") { openWindow(id: "AppSettings") }
    }
}
```

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate: AppDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        Window("Settings", id: "AppSettings") {
            SettingsView().environmentObject(appState)
        }.windowResizability(.contentSize)

        Settings {
            SettingsView().environmentObject(appState)
        }
    }
```

```swift
@MainActor class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        getWindowById(id: "AppSettings")?.close()
    }
}

func getWindowById(id: String) -> NSWindow? {
    return NSApp.windows.first { window in
        if let identifier = window.identifier {
            return identifier.rawValue == id
        }
        return false
    }
}
```