# How to open my own app settings (not the system's) with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I've seen a few places how to open the system settings, but what I'm looking for is how to open **my app's** settings.

The use case is that I have a macOS app with a menu in the MenuBarExtra with the `.menuBarExtraStyle(.window)`. In that menu I have a button that should open my app's settings, but I have no clue how to do it. I haven't found anything useful in the docs, and any search that I make returns how to open the system settings.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/72803389/5452969 I've flagged it as duplicate just in case the title of this question helps people find the solution. Existing titles didn't help me.