# Opening SwiftUI Settings from AppKit

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit

On macOS 14, the way to open the settings has changed. The code I have been using so far is:

```
if #available(macOS 13, *) {
    NSApp.sendAction(Selector(("showSettingsWindow:")), to: nil, from: nil)
} else {
    NSApp.sendAction(Selector(("showPreferencesWindow:")), to: nil, from: nil)
}
```

On macOS 14, this code throws the error message `Please use SettingsLink for opening the Settings scene.`

Actual Question: How can I open the app settings programmatically from AppKit in macOS 14 (Sonoma)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to programatically open Settings/Preferences window in a macOS SwiftUI App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65355696/how-to-programatically-open-settings-preferences-window-in-a-macos-swiftui-app)

Comment: The referenced question has two answers about SettingsLink.

Comment: I saw that question and I'm using SettingsLink already in case I have to open the settings from a SwiftUI view. But I don't have a solution for the MenuBarExtra app yet.

Comment: I switched to the SwiftUI way of creating a MenuBarExtra app. Until 14, I used AppKit. Now I'm using SwiftUI. This solves my personal issue. Not sure if this solves the issue for other AppKit users though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the new method:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        RootScreen()
    }

    Settings {
        SettingsScreen()
    }

    MenuBarExtra("My App", systemImage: "mic.fill") {
        SettingsLink {
           Text("Settings")
        }
    }
    .keyboardShortcut(".", modifiers: .command)
}
```

#### Alternative if you have `NSMenu`

https://github.com/orchetect/SettingsAccess

```
import SettingsAccess

final class AppDelegateMac: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    private func setupStatusBar() {
        let menu = NSMenu()
        menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Settings", action: #selector(openSettings), keyEquivalent: ""))

        statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: CGFloat(NSStatusItem.variableLength))
        statusBarItem!.menu = menu
        statusBarItem!.button?.image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "mic.fill", accessibilityDescription: nil)
    }

    @objc private func openSettings() {
        if #available(macOS 14, *) {
            appState?.openSettingsSignal.send()
        }
    }
}

---

import SettingsAccess

@main
struct MyApp: App {

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            RootScreen()
                .openSettingsAccess()
        }
    }
}

---

struct RootScreen: View {

    private let appState: AppState
    @Environment(\.openSettings) var openSettings

    var body: some View {
    }
    .onReceive(appState.openSettingsSignal) {
        try? openSettings()
    }
}

---

struct AppState {
    let openSettingsSignal = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I ended up using `if #available` together with the method as proposed by you. I didn't use the `MenuBarExtra`-SwiftUI way of doing things until now. For macOS 14 I'm using this and it works as expected.